# Chat room in erlang with cowboy and websocket

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I'm trying to create a chatroom with cowboy websocket handler.
I want that messages those come from every will be forwarded to other sockets as well, just like a chat group.
I don't have any idea how to implement this?
And I don't know how to save sockets that are connected to websocket so we can send messages to them.
I have this cowboy handler:

```
-module(chat_conn).

-export([ init/2
    , websocket_init/1
    , websocket_handle/2
    , websocket_info/2
    , terminate/3
    ]).

-include("chat.hrl").

init(Req, [WsConnIdleTimeout]) ->
    ?LOG_DEBUG("[CHAT-CONN] New HTTP Request on: /api , Pid: ~p", [self()]),
    WsOpts = #{idle_timeout => WsConnIdleTimeout},
    State = #{counter => 0},
    {cowboy_websocket, Req, State, WsOpts}.

websocket_init(State0) ->
    ?LOG_DEBUG("[FOOZI-CONN] HTTP Upgraded to WebSocketm pid: ~p", [self()]),
    NewState = State0,
    {ok, NewState}.

websocket_handle({text, PlainRequest}, #{counter := Counter0} = State) ->
    ?LOG_DEBUG("[HIGGS-CONN] Receive New Message: ~p, Pid: ~p" , [PlainRequest, self()]),
    NewCounter = Counter0 + 1,
    Reply = list_to_binary("Counter is: " ++ integer_to_list(NewCounter)),
    NewState = #{counter => NewCounter},
    {reply, {text, Reply}, NewState};
    %{ok, State};
websocket_handle(Frame, State) ->
    ?LOG_INFO("[HIGGS-CONN] Invalid Frame => ~p", [Frame]),
    {stop, State}.

websocket_info(Message, State) ->
    ?LOG_INFO("[CONN-INFO] Unhandled message! => Message: ~p", [Message]),
    {reply, {text, list_to_binary(Message)}, State}.
    %{ok, State}.

terminate(Reason, _, State) ->
    ?LOG_INFO("[CONN-TERMINATE] Terminated! => Pid: ~p, Reason: ~p, State: ~p", [self(), Reason, State]),
    ok.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know how to save sockets that are connected to websocket so we
> can send messages to them

In erlang, gen_servers can be used to store state, so you can create a `gen_server` that the websocket handlers employ to save the client pids.  When a client sends a "start chat" message to your cowboy server using a specific route, the associated websocket handler will be called.  Inside that handler, `self()` will be the pid of the websocket process for that client.  You can save that pid in your `gen_server` by calling `gen_server:cast(chat_room, {arrive, self()})`, then inside `chat_room:handle_cast()` adding the pid to the list of pids stored in the `State` variable.

When the cowboy server receives a chat message from a client browser, the client's websocket process will handle the message, and inside the appropriate websocket handler you can query the `gen_server` to get a list of the pids for the connected clients.  Then you can use `!` to send each of them the message.  In turn, each client's `websocket_info()` handler will handle the message, which it can relay through the websocket back to the client by returning: `{reply, {text, Text}, State}`.

For your `gen_server`, you will also need to implement a `leave()` function that the appropriate websocket handler will call to update the list of clients stored in the `gen_server`, e.g. `gen_server:cast(chat_room, {leave, self()})`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this response. I would really appreciate if you could kindly link to any resources for building cowboy/websockets based chat.. I am sufficiently familiar with regular cowboy servers.